# SCHED_RR vs SCHED_FIFO what order?

Tags: c, linux, process, scheduled-tasks, round-robin

I have an exam and there is a huge confusion which I need to fix.

I know that the difference between SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR is that among tasks with the same priority, SCHED_RR performs a round-robin with a certain timeslice; SCHED_FIFO, instead, needs the task to explicitly yield the processor.

Plus, I know that if there is a real-time process in the system no "regular" process will run.

But what I can't understand how RR and FIFO will run together?

Let's say I have the following processes all with same priority, while (f) means it's FIFO and (r) means RR ordered from the one which came first to the latest:

A(r), B(f), C(f), D(r), E(r)

1. In which order will they run?
2. What if I change A to (f)?
3. Now what if I have two processes A and B where A came before B and A is RR while B is FIFO what's the order?
4. What if A is FIFO not and B is RR?

I other words,  I don't know what's more important when we have RR and FIFO together, is it who came first, is it who has more priority or is it always FIFO?

Comment: Mostly guesses, so not an answer. As I understand, the only difference between a `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR` thread is that a `SCHED_FIFO` thread will keep running unless it yields, is blocked, or is preempted by a higher priority thread, where a `SCHED_RR` thread will eventually run out of time. Logically, for 3, thread A would run until its time slice ends, at which point B will run until it yields.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Red Hat Reference Guide [Chapter 5. Priorities and Policies](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/7/html/reference_guide/chap-priorities_and_policies#:%7E:text=A%20SCHED_FIFO%20thread%20with%20a,SCHED_FIFO%20is%20preferred%20over%20SCHED_RR%20):

> Generally, SCHED_FIFO is preferred over SCHED_RR.

I think FIFO would come first when we have both runnable FIFO and RR in the same static priority list.